# Django on Jython with Oracle: Too many open cursors

Tags: django, oracle, jython

I am running Django on Jython with Oracle and I often get the famous

> "Too many open cursors"

error.

It never happens with the same code with Python and the cx_Oracle driver.

Is there something wrong with the zxJDBC driver or perhaps there is a way to ask Django to close the cursors when I am done with the querysets?

Thanks,

Stephane

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a closing problem to me.

I think the `with` keyword is supposed to help with closing resources in Python.  I don't know if connection handling is something that Django does for you or if you still have to manage them in your code, but perhaps that would be one way to address it.